# Why this SHACL validation does not work as expected?

Tags: rdf, shacl

Here is my shacl.ttl:

```
@prefix ex: <http://datashapes.org/sh/tests/core/path/path-sequence-003.test#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .

ex:paintNodeShape
  rdf:type sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:property ex:ColorProperty ;
  sh:targetNode ex:John .

ex:ColorProperty
  rdf:type sh:PropertyShape ;
  sh:qualifiedValueShape [  
      sh:path (ex:paint  ex:ballColor ) ;
      sh:hasValue "Red" ;
     ] ;
  sh:qualifiedMinCount 2 .
```

and here is data.ttl:

```
@prefix ex: <http://datashapes.org/sh/tests/core/path/path-sequence-003.test#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .

ex:John
  ex:paint [ ex:ballColor "Red"] ;
  ex:paint [ ex:ballColor "Red"] ;
  ex:paint [ ex:ballColor "Blue"] .
```

I want to verify that John painted at least two balls red, and the data given should meet the requirements.  But I got an error message:  "Less than 2 values have shape _:22728aa9248d56603d8c20009b9d6742" .
Is there something wrong with my sequence path?  Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shape definition is a bit different from how the SHACL examples for `sh:qualifiedValueShape` go. I believe the property shape might need `sh:path ex:paint` to really match the property, like this:

```
ex:ColorProperty
  rdf:type sh:PropertyShape ;
  sh:path ex:paint ;
  sh:qualifiedValueShape [  
      sh:path ex:ballColor ;
      sh:hasValue "Red" ;
     ] ;
  sh:qualifiedMinCount 2 .
```

This should represent a shape for the values of the `ex:paint` property.